# ASP.NET: webservice Returns {object[0]} instead of int

Tags: asp.net, web-services

i've got the following simple webservice :

```
     [WebMethod()]
public int Add(int a)
{
    return a + 1;
}
```

i've created a class to call it (without creating a wsdl and then a proxy).
something like:

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(
Name = "Addrequest",
Namespace = "GenieSoft")]
public class Addrequest :
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
public Addrequest()
{
    this.Url = "http://localhost:3880/SoapService/Service.asmx";
}
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute(
"GenieSoft/Add",
RequestNamespace = "GenieSoft",
ResponseNamespace = "GenieSoft",
Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal,
ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
public  object[] Add(int a )
{
    object[] results = this.Invoke("Add",new object[] { a });
    return results;
}
}
```

i create an object of the class and then try to call the webservice as follows:

```
  Addrequest request = new Addrequest();
    object[] returnedArray =  request.Add(1);

     //object i = returnedArray[0]; // i is equal to  {object[0]} !
    lblresult.InnerText = returnedArray[0].ToString();
```

i've tested it with debug locally and the webservice is getting called and receiving the sent int "1"  and returning  "2" , however when i try to check the returnedArray all i find is  {object[0]} which as i understand is another array of size 0 .

Can someone help me, by pointing out the problem ?

**Note:** i got this example of the book Programming Web Applications with Soap by O'Reilly , i only changed it from string to int , and i've tested it both ways -as a string and as an int- and got the same result for both tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem, Obviously the return dataType of the calling function causes the problem ( object[] ) ,while it is (int) in the webservice . to solve the problem i modified the webservice to return an object[] instead of an int (could've also modified the Add in the calling class to return int) something like this :

```
public object[] Add(int a)
{
    object[] objects = { a + 1 };
    return objects;
}
```